# Вопрос касательно Radiobutton в TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

На моей форме существует три радиобаттона, при выборе которых создаются поля для заполнения (задача - написать тест). Не могу никак додуматься, как можно сделать удаление или скрытие элементов других радиобаттонов, если они уже были нажаты...  ( То есть, нажали на один радиобаттон - создали элементы формы для заполнения, нажали на другой радиобаттон - ранее созданные элементы удаляются и создаются новые) [image: ter]

Comment: Я бы попросил привести пример кода, а вообще 3 функции отрисовки этих форм и свич например

Answer (score 2):

Как пример вроде как понятный, но если возникнут вопросы спрашивайте

```
import tkinter as tk


def func():
    if var.get():
        label.pack_forget()
        text.pack()

    else:
        text.pack_forget()
        label.pack()


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
text = tk.Text()
text.insert(tk.END, "Тоже какой то текст")

label = tk.Label(text="Какой то текст")

var = tk.IntVar()
r_1 = tk.Radiobutton(text="Функция Label", variable=var, value=0, command=func)
r_2 = tk.Radiobutton(text="Функция Text", variable=var, value=1, command=func)
r_1.pack()
r_2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]